# Is there a way to read an image from a url on openCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to read an image which is on a website, I am passing image link to `cv2.imgread(https://website.com/photo.jpg)` for example.  But it returns a `NoneType`.  The error says `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object`

HERE's my code:

```
def get_isbn(x):
    print(x)
    
    image = cv2.imread(x)
    
    
    print(type(image))
    detectedBarcodes = decode(image)
    for barcode in detectedBarcodes:
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 5)

        # print(barcode.data)
        # print(type(barcode.data))
        byte_isbn = barcode.data
        string_isbn = str(byte_isbn, encoding='utf-8')
        
        return string_isbn
```

x is my url as a param.

Comment: Try VideoCapture with the string url

Comment: I just want to work on an image,

Comment: VideoCapture can read image files. Maybe it can  also read image fils urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert link to array and then decode it with opencv.

**function**

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2
def url_to_image(url):
    resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image
```

**Merge in your code**

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2
def url_to_image(url):
    resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
    image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    return image
def get_isbn(x):
    print(x)

image = url_to_image(x)


print(type(image))
detectedBarcodes = decode(image)
for barcode in detectedBarcodes:
    (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 5)

    # print(barcode.data)
    # print(type(barcode.data))
    byte_isbn = barcode.data
    string_isbn = str(byte_isbn, encoding='utf-8')
    
    return string_isbn
```

Comment: It's awesome. Also merge in code worked for me. This code replaces cv2.imread for url read.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases we can read the image as if it were a video composed of single frame.

It's not going to work in all cases, and it's not efficient in terms of execution time.
The advantage is that the solution uses only OpenCV package (it may also work in C++ for example).

Code sample:

```python
import cv2

image_url = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIDkn.jpg'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(image_url)  # Open the URL as video

success, image = cap.read()  # Read the image as a video frame

if success:
    cv2.imshow('image ', image)  # Display the image for testing
    cv2.waitKey()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```